# Queuing byte data in java

Tags: java, android

I want to stream data over network continuously. The source gives me a byte array that I'd want to store in a data structure which serves as buffer to compensate for any network lags.

What is the most efficient data structure to store the bytes in a queue fashion. Think of it as a pipe where one thread pumps in the data and other one reads and sends it over the network, while the pipe itself is long enough to contain multiple frames of the input data.

Is Queue efficient enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **Queue** would not be efficient if you put `byte`s in one at a time.  It would eat lots of memory, create GC pressure, and slow things down.

You could make the overhead of **Queue**s reasonable if you put reasonably-sized (say 64kB) `byte[]`s or `ByteBuffer`s in them.  That buffer size could be tunable and changed based on performance experiments or perhaps even be adaptive at runtime.

TCP already compensates for network lags.  If you are using UDP then you will need to handle congestion properly or things will go badly.  In practice using TCP or UDP directly creates a lot of extra work and reinvention of wheels.

[ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) (or the pure Java [JeroMQ](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq)) is a good library option with an efficient wire protocol (good enough for realtime stock trading platforms).  It handles the queueing transparently and gives a lot of options for different client models including things like PUB SUB that would help if you have lots of clients on a broadcast.  Within a process ZeroMQ can manage the queueing of data being producuers and consumers.  You could even use it to efficiently broadcast the same bytes to workers that do independent things with the same stream (ex: one doing usage metering and another doing transcoding).

There are other libraries that may also work.  I think [Netty](http://netty.io/) handles things like this efficiently for example.

Comment: I'm more interested in the data structure , network transmission is just an application using it and can change, for example if I want to process the data locally instead of transmitting it.

Comment: Interesting. In that case ZeroMQ is still good because it works for well for highly efficient intra-process (between threads) work as well.

Comment: hmm :(  nothing from the api bundled with JDK ?

Comment: You can definitely do this with the JDK's **Queue**s if you can find a reasonable size for the buffers you put on them that trades latency of filling the buffer with memory savings of not having huge numbers of queue elements. It's a tricky thing to tune, but certainly achievable.

Comment: Yeah that's what I originally intended to do put small chunks of data as byte [] into the queue, but wasn't sure if it would kill it given the rate at which the data is put in and out. but now from your reasoning I think queues will be fine for small data

Comment: @user1062760 I think you're set then. It's likely that the buffer size will need tuning so I recommend making it tunable and having a way to measure performance :)

Answer (score -1):

You should look into the OKIO libraray

Comment: I'm downvoting because there is no clear explanation of why **OKIO** would solve the problem.

Comment: Some users are able to google and just need the right keyword